# Can I pass js variable to R chunk?

Tags: javascript, r

Is it possible to get selected option value to R chunk?(R markdown with HTML)
I want to use a dropdown list to select the variable `i` and use it to subset my table. Here I use `iris[i]` for example.

I am not familiar with JS and I really hope somebody could give me some advice.

````
```{js echo = FALSE}
window.onload = function(){
    var obj_select = document.getElementById("test_select");
}
```
<select id="test_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="test">
```{r}
i <- JS(......)
iris[i]
```
</div>
````

Comment: You can do it in a Shiny app using the methods described here:  https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html.  It's not easy.

Comment: @ user2554330 Thank you for your comment. I can only use shiny (with server) to achieve js action in rmarkdown,is it right?

Comment: I think there are other frameworks to do the same sort of thing, but Shiny is the most popular one.

Comment: @user2554330 Appreciate your reply!  So there is no simple way to solve it with standalone rmarkdown html file without server right?